# How to give onclick event in specific joomla menu?

Tags: joomla

Hi I have five menu items " Home, About us, Archives, Services, Contact us" they all comes from mod_mainmenu modules and on Archives i need to put onclick event how can i do that?
Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the above poster said, it is not good practice to hack core files.  However, take a look into Template Overrides and you can copy the referenced php document into the template's html directory, which will override the core component.  In this way, the core component can still be updated when you update/upgrade Joomla, and your override file will take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

find the file `modules/mod_mainmennu/helper.php`

find the comment `// Print a link if it exists`

and in `switch` case while generating `<a href=....`  you can add `onlick =" function()"`

This is not good practice to hack the core files. You must create another module and render it.

Or user JQuery to work on `onclick` event of links.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very easy way to do that.
In the URL input field in Joomla, close th url with a " then a space then onClick="yourJavaScript; but don't put the ending "
In other words:

```
http://yourwebsite.com" onClick="yourJavaScript;
```

Simple really

Comment: the weird thing is it's working for one of my websites but not for the other, and they are running the same version of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

> In the URL input field in Joomla, close th url with a " then a space then onClick="yourJavaScript; but don't put the ending "

This solution does not work because Joomla will strip out the " in the string (the one before onClick.
Otherwise, it would have been fantastic :)